# Create new table that merges 2 tables together if they have the same date and time?

Tags: r, date, join, time, merge

I have 2 tables that look similar to this:

```
data1 <- data.frame("Metal" = c("Al", "Al", "Al", "Al", "Al", "Al", "Al"), "Type" = c("F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F"), "Date" = c("2000-01-01", "2000-01-01", "2000-01-02", "2000-01-03", 
"2000-01-03", "2000-01-07", "2000-01-07"), "Time" = c("11:00:00", "12:00:00", "15:00:00", "13:00:00", "17:00:00", "20:00:00", "20:00:00"))

data2 <- data.frame("Metal" = c("Al", "Al", "Al", "Al", "Al"), "Type" = c("P", "P", 
"P", "P", "P"), "Date" = c("2000-01-01", "2000-01-01", "2000-01-03", "2000-01-03", 
"2000-01-04"), "Time" = c("11:00:00", "14:00:00", "17:00:00", "13:00:00", "16:00:00"))
```

I want to keep data from both tables that have the same date and time. So the final table (data3) would look like this.

```
data3 <- data.frame("Metal" = c("Al", "Al", "Al", "Al"), "Type" = c("F", "P", "F", 
"P"), "Date" = c("2000-01-01", "2000-01-01", "2000-01-03", "2000-01-03", "2000-01-03"), "Time" = 
c("11:00:00", "11:00:00", "13:00:00", "13:00:00", "17:00:00"))
```

I've been trying various types of joins in dplyr, but none of them are doing the join the way I want them too. They either only keep data in 1 table or keep too much of the data.

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: How about when time is `17:00:00`...Arent those the same?

Comment: @Sotos yes you are correct. I also need to edit for a different type of scenario...

Answer (score 0):

You can `rbind` and keep only the duplicates (except from column `type`), i.e.

```
d3 <- rbind(data1, data2)
d3[duplicated(d3[-2])|duplicated(d3[-2], fromLast = TRUE),]

  Metal Type       Date     Time
1    Al    F 2000-01-01 11:00:00
4    Al    F 2000-01-03 13:00:00
5    Al    F 2000-01-03 17:00:00
6    Al    P 2000-01-01 11:00:00
8    Al    P 2000-01-03 17:00:00
9    Al    P 2000-01-03 13:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you this did work for that particular subset! I realized though that in my actual dataset, I have some duplicates in both tables. I added in the final row of data1 that situation. In your code, it will keep both of those rows in data1 in data3 because it is a duplicate, but I don't want it to keep it because there's no match in data2. Could you help me solve this? Thank you!!

Comment: It will output both of the 20:00:00 time stamps from data1 with that logic.